# Making a multidimensional tensor

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tensorflow

I have a list a 3d image represented in an array of size 50x50x50. Every element of this 3D array is a pixel. I've differentiated every pixel in the x,y,z direction. How can I represent this in the array?

After differentiating it, I get a list of size 3, and within each index is a 50,50,50. This is therefore a list has the differentiated image for x,y and z direction, which is very nearly what I want. But I would like an array which was 50,50,50,3 rather than 3,50,50,50. 
[This is what I would want represented. Every pixel has a value for x,y and z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw813.png)

My code:

```
array_image=full_image[0:50,0:50,0:50] 
Gradient=np.gradient(array_image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `np.gradient` doc carefully, it actually returns what you want but with different shape.

> gradient : ndarray or list of ndarray. 
>       A set of ndarrays (or a single ndarray if there is only one dimension)
>       corresponding to the derivatives of f with respect to each dimension.
>       Each derivative has the same shape as f.

So your `Gradient` is a list of gradients for `array_image`, corresponding to the each dimension.

```py
res = np.zeros([50,50,50,3])
for i in range(3):
    res[:,:,:,i] = Gradient[i]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped a lot!!